# How do I save all the citizens in the first Masyaf key mission?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In the first Masyaf key mission in Assassin's Creed: Revelations, I have to save all citizens in order to achieve 100% synchronization.

Are they before the gate and the crusader? Or do I have to somehow make sure the crusader doesn't kill more hostages than necessary?

Who do I have to save and how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This confused me as well. The citizens are before the gate.
What you need to do is run around the area you start at, looking for small black circles on your minimap, these mark areas where templars are attacking a citizen, simply go there and kill them off, when you took care of all of these you'll see the message for optional objective completed.

Comment: Just to be explicit, *the hostages do not count*.  Some will die no matter what you do.

Comment: Well, that clears things up. Really bad in-game description, I was convinced I was doing something wrong to get that first hostage killed! Gave up eventually...

Comment: omg you have no idea how many times i tried this, i thought they meant the hostages!! and the icons are not easy to spot on the map, i mean sure i saw them but i thought they were towers or something... Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

What shinrai said is correct, there are three black dots faintly highlighted in white. That's where you save the citizens. you just kind of run around the area to locate them . They will just pop up. when you have saved all the citizens it will prompt you that you have successfuy done so. This all happens before you reach the castle gate.

Comment: How does that add to the accepted answer?